# Basic conditional adding a full second to load time

Tags: conditionals, speed

I have the following code in my blog index template:

```
<section class="blog-listing">
    {if "{freebie_2}" == ""}
        {exp:channel:entries
            channel="blog"
            disable="categories custom_fields member_data pagination"
            dynamic="no"
            limit='{exp:low_variables:parse var="articles_per_page"}'
            parse="inward"
            status='{exp:stash:get 
                name="preview_status"
                file="yes"
                parse_tags="yes"
                parse_conditionals="yes"
            }'
        }
            {article_snippet}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/if}
    {if "{freebie_2}" == "column"}
        {exp:channel:entries
            channel="blog"
            category="{exp:freebie:category_id segment='3'}"
            dynamic="no"
            limit='{exp:low_variables:parse var="articles_per_page"}'
            status='{exp:stash:get 
                name="preview_status"
                file="yes"
                parse_tags="yes"
                parse_conditionals="yes"
            }'
            parse="inward"
        }
            {article_snippet}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/if}
</section>
```

Currently this page is taking on average 2.97 seconds to load. I started removing pieces here and there to see if I could get to the bottom of what's slowing it down, and I just may have. It seems it may actually be the basic `{if}` statements!

If I remove the second one completely the page load time averages out to 1.58 seconds. I thought it might be Freebie, so I changed it to `{if "columns" == "column"}` and it took just as long.

Is this a known issue? What might be the root cause of this? I'm on *blazing fast* servers and this shouldn't be happening.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To a conditional to be considered a simple one, it needs to use snippets or early parsed variables. This isn't the case when you're using **freebie**. Unlike **Low Seg2cat**, that parses really earlier on parsing stages, Freebie parses together with all modules.

Can you remove freebie? If you can, try this:

```
<section class="blog-listing">
    {if segment_X == ""}
        {exp:channel:entries
            channel="blog"
            disable="categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination"
            dynamic="no"
            limit='{exp:low_variables:parse var="articles_per_page"}'
            parse="inward"
            status='{exp:stash:get 
                name="preview_status"
                file="yes"
                parse_tags="yes"
                parse_conditionals="yes"
            }'
        }
            {article_snippet}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/if}
    {if segment_X == "column"}
        {exp:channel:entries
            channel="blog"
            category="{exp:freebie:category_id segment='3'}"
            dynamic="no"
            limit='{exp:low_variables:parse var="articles_per_page"}'
            status='{exp:stash:get 
                name="preview_status"
                file="yes"
                parse_tags="yes"
                parse_conditionals="yes"
            }'
            parse="inward"
        }
            {article_snippet}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/if}
    {if segment_X != "column" AND segment_X != ""}
        {redirect="404"}
    {/if}
</section>
```

The unnecessary `exp:channel:entries` will be removed before parsing.

I thought about to put the conditionals inside the `exp:channel:entries` opening tag, but this will allow its parsing in case of `segment_X != 'column' AND segment_X != ""` and the first step to get better performance is to prevent unnecessary parsing. I added a `return="404"` just to emphasize this case and remind you that it's possible for you to have an empty `<section>`.

If you can't remove freebie, [switchee](https://github.com/croxton/Switchee/tree/develop) is your alternative:

```
<section class="blog-listing">
{exp:switchee variable = "{freebie_2}" parse="inward"}
    {case value=""}
        {exp:channel:entries
            channel="blog"
            disable="categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination"
            dynamic="no"
            limit='{exp:low_variables:parse var="articles_per_page"}'
            parse="inward"
            status='{exp:stash:get 
                name="preview_status"
                file="yes"
                parse_tags="yes"
                parse_conditionals="yes"
            }'
        }
            {article_snippet}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/case}

    {case value="column"}
        {exp:channel:entries
            channel="blog"
            category="{exp:freebie:category_id segment='3'}"
            dynamic="no"
            limit='{exp:low_variables:parse var="articles_per_page"}'
            status='{exp:stash:get 
                name="preview_status"
                file="yes"
                parse_tags="yes"
                parse_conditionals="yes"
            }'
            parse="inward"
        }
            {article_snippet}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/case}
    {case default="yes"}
                {redirect="404"}
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
</section>
```

Please, let me to know if any of the suggestions doesn't work.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much. This was a major wake-up call for me.

Comment: Question: I have a bunch of `{if}` statements in my `{article_snippet}` (approximately 30). Should I consider replacing those with another technique like Switchee? What if there will only ever be one condition (no else statement)?

Comment: This really doesn't matter. Conditionals inside a module tag are all parsed, except on some module that have their own parsing functions, like switchee. In your case, as both `exp:channel:entries` uses parse="inward", this matter even less.

Answer (score 1):

Templates are parsed in a certain order of functionality - not a top down approach.

In your instance the two exp:channel:entries tags are being parsed first (so double the performance hit), then EE looks at the conditionals and removes the output of the irrelevant part of the conditional.

So **either** you have to place a single channel entries in an embed - embeds don't get included and parsed until after conditionals (so no double call overhead)...

***blog/index template:***

```
<section class="blog-listing">
{if "{freebie_2}" == ""}
    {embed=blog/listing
        category=""
        limit='{exp:low_variables:parse var="articles_per_page"}'
        status='{exp:stash:get 
            name="preview_status"
            file="yes"
            parse_tags="yes"
            parse_conditionals="yes"
        }'
    }
{if:elseif "{freebie_2}" == "column"}
    {embed=blog/listing
        category="{exp:freebie:category_id segment='3'}"
        limit='{exp:low_variables:parse var="articles_per_page"}'
        status='{exp:stash:get 
            name="preview_status"
            file="yes"
            parse_tags="yes"
            parse_conditionals="yes"
        }'
    }
{/if}
</section>
```

***blog/listing template:***

```
{exp:channel:entries
        channel="blog"
        category="{embed:category}"
        disable="categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination"
        dynamic="no"
        limit="{embed:limit}"
        parse="inward"
        status="{embed:status}"
    }
    {article_snippet}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

...Or try merging both channel entries into a single call using simply conditionals...

```
<section class="blog-listing">
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="blog"
        category="{if segment_2 == "column"}{exp:freebie:category_id segment='3'}{/if}"
        disable="categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination"
        dynamic="no"
        limit='{exp:low_variables:parse var="articles_per_page"}'
        parse="inward"
        status='{exp:stash:get 
            name="preview_status"
            file="yes"
            parse_tags="yes"
            parse_conditionals="yes"
        }'
    }
        {article_snippet}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</section>
```

Your disable tag is incorrect btw:

```
disable="categories custom_fields member_data pagination"
```

should be

```
disable="categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination"
```

[ref](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#disable)